# If $T(t)$ is a semigroup and $x$ satisfies $\left\|T(h)x-x\right\|\to0$ as $h\to0$, are we able to conclude that $t\mapsto T(t)x$ is continous?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

Let $E$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space and $(T(t))_{t\ge0}$ be a semigroup on $E$.

> **Definition**:
>
> 1. If $x\in E$, then $(T(t))_{t\ge0}$ is called *strongly continuous at $x$* iff $$[0,\infty)\to E\;,\;\;\;t\mapsto T(t)x\tag1$$ is continuous
> 2. $(T(t))_{t\ge0}$ is called *locally bounded*$^1$ iff $$\exists t>0:\sup_{s\in[0,\:t)}\left\|T(s)\right\|_{\mathfrak L(E)}<\infty\tag2$$

**Question**: Let $x\in E$ with $$\left\|T(h)x-x\right\|_E\xrightarrow{h\to0+}0\tag4.$$ Are able to show that $(T(t))_{t\ge0}$ is strongly continuous at $x$?

It's easy to see that $(1)$ is right-continuous. Moreover, I'm able to show that $(1)$ is left-coninuous, **as long as I assume that $(T(t))_{t\ge0}$ is locally bounded**.

> Are we able to drop the local boundedness assumption and still conclude the left-continuity?

My idea is as follows: By $(4)$, $$\exists t>0:\forall h\in[0,t):\left\|T(h)x\right\|_E<1+\left\|x\right\|_E\tag5$$ and maybe we are able to show local boundedness by the [uniform boundedness principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle) in some way.

---

$^1$ By the semigroup property, $(1)$ implies that $$\sup_{s\in I}\left\|T(s)\right\|_{\mathfrak L(E)}<\infty$$ for each bounded interval $I\subseteq[0,\infty)$.

Comment: @cmk No, it's not the *definition* of continuity with respect to the strong operator topology (SOT). The mapping $T:[0,\infty)\to\mathfrak L(E)$ is continuous at $t\ge0$ with respect to the SOT iff $$\left\|T(t+h)-T(t)\right\|_E\xrightarrow{h\to0}0\tag6.$$ And that's what we need to show from $(4)$.

Comment: @cmk Did I wrote that the SOT is the same as the UOT? And the Wikipedia article doesn't help to solve the problem. They make use of the fact a semigroup is strongly continuous iff $(1)$ is continuous at $0$ (i.e. $(4)$ holds) for all $x\in E$, but this equivalence needs to be proven. And my question is different, since I don't want to assume that all orbits are continuous (which might be crucial).

Comment: @cmk Strong continuity is continuity for the strong operator topology which is induced by the family of seminorms $\|T\|_x = \|Tx\|$ as $x$ ranges over $E$. For general maps $t \mapsto T_t$ this yields a strictly stronger condition that what you call the definition (which is right-continuity at $t=0$ for the S.O.T.). The point is that e.g. the Wikipedia page you link to gives a characterisation of strong continuity that can be shown to be equivalent to the definition given the other two assumptions. OP essentially wants a proof of that equivalence and so your comments are bad criticisms.

Comment: @0xbadf00d If I'm not mistaken, the answer I just gave to your other question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3266357/if-tt-is-a-semigroup-on-e-and-b-is-a-subspace-of-e-such-that-left-t/3266385#3266385) also resolves the issue you have in answering this question.

Comment: @RhysSteele Unfortunately not. Your answer yields the following: Let $E_0$ denote the set on which $(4)$ holds. Then if $E_0=E$, $(T(t))_{t\ge0}$ is locally bounded (on $E$) by your answer. And this yields (again by $E_0=E$ and the argument in my question) that $(T(t))_{t\ge0}$ is strongly continuous. And actually I think this is all we can show. If we only know $(4)$ for that particular $x$, it seems like we need to assume local boundedness of $(T(t))_{t\ge0}$ (on $E$) explicitly.

Comment: @cmk Be aware that the proof of the equivalence utilizes the semigroup property. So, it's not an equivalent characterization of continuity wrt the SOT in general.

Comment: @cmk Apologies if I misread your intention. I don't think my reading was unreasonable though. Especially the comment "See Evans, Rudin, even Wikipedia..." has the tone of someone implying OP doesn't know what they are talking about (especially "even Wikipedia" which implies OP hasn't checked the most basic sources). That tone wouldn't be particularly congruent with someone who was just questioning.